# Sqlite3 - can't use characters with diacritics

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, encoding

I'm creating a method which takes a name as an argument and returns a row from `Sqlite3` database. When trying to use non-diacritic characters, it works.

But if I try to pass a `string` which contains diacritic characters, it raises:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to print the same name to the console, it works.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

def get_subject_by_name(name): # TODO: APROXIMATE SEARCH
    result = cur.execute("""SELECT nazov,ICO,pravna_forma,sidlo,predmet_cinnosti,den_zapisu,url_orsr FROM companies WHERE nazov LIKE ?""",('{}%'.format(name),)).fetchall()
    print result

get_subject_by_name(u"systém")
```

do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from your `format`:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '{}%'.format(u'syst\xe9m')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You're trying to format a Unicode string into a byte string and Python 2 tries to coerce the Unicode string into a byte string using the default `ascii` codec.

Use Unicode strings everywhere:

```
>>> u'{}%'.format(u'syst\xe9m')
u'syst\xe9m%'
```

Including your SELECT:

```
result = cur.execute(u"""SELECT nazov,ICO,pravna_forma,sidlo,predmet_cinnosti,den_zapisu,url_orsr FROM companies WHERE nazov LIKE ?""",(u'{}%'.format(name),)).fetchall()
```